# PowerShell Script to remove Security Permission from Folders

Tags: powershell, permissions, scripting

Using PowerShell, I am looking for a little help to remove certain built in domain accounts from a folder under the users Home folder.

I have already written code to remove inheritance, but I can't seem to figure out how to remove certain built-in Domain accounts.

The home folder and a private folder are created with the script then I would like to remove Domain\Users and Domain\Domain Users from the folder permissions.

Comment: Try solution from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29018582/powerscript-acl-folder-access-remove-user-groups-privlages

Comment: Yea, that code is not working. I have tried it. The OP was on the point, but the answer offers a solution that does not work, and the OP posted the final code block which does not do what I am trying to do. But it was close.

Comment: just FYI, before you ask me for the error on someone else's code, here it is: SetSecurityDescriptor, does not exist.